# How I can add information about story id to Scenarion by using allure-cucumber-jvm-adaptor?

Tags: allure

I have feature files with sceneries :

```
Feature: <description of feature>
@Story-1
Scenarion: first
        Given ....
        When ...
        Then ...
@Story-2        
Scenarion: second
        Given ....
        When ...
        Then ...
```

How I can add information about story to allure report? Is it possible to add it to scenario name only in report? I can`t find information about how to work with cucumber tags and allure report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fix problem in new cucumber allure plugin. Add annotation before scenario.

```
@TestCaseId("Test-1001")
```

Link to new plugin:

Maven repo: http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccom.github.kirlionik%7Callure-cucumber-plugin%7C1.0.1%7Cjar

GitHub wiki: https://github.com/kirlionik/allure-cucumber-plugin/wiki

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes